# How to Rollback the entire process when database error occurs within the loop?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Consider two MicroServices ( 1 & 2), 1st Service retrieves the data from the user and sends the data to the 2nd Service where the data gets stored in the database. This takes place in a loop.

For example, consider the length of the loop as 5. When each time it iterates, it calls the rest service and saves the data to the database. Suppose, while iterating for the 3rd time, the service2 throws some error and the execution stops, and the remaining data are not stored in the Database. Now my question **is there any way I can remove the other two data which got saved to Database successfully without writing a separate function for removing the data individually?**
**Is there any way to roll back the entire process when an error occurs within the loop?**

**Microservice-1**

```
class MicroService1 {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    void rollBack(){

         String [] name={"hello","hai","hey"};

         for(String n: name){
              
              MyObject object=new MyObject();
              object.setName( n );
              try{
                 restTemplate.postForEntity("micorservice-2",object,String.class);
              } catch(){
                   .....
               }
         }

     }
}
```

**Microservice-2**

```
class MicroService2 {

        @Autowired
        private MyRepository repo;

          //Template call comes to this function and saves the data to the database
           
          void saveData(MyObject obj){
             try{
                 repository.save(obj);

             } catch(Exception ex) {
                ....
             }
          }
}
```

Comment: As an alternative to the (great) answer you already got, you may want to take a look at the Saga pattern

Comment: oh man .. great .. thanks @crizzis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every external rest call is technically independent from each other, and every request starts a new transaction in MicroService2. These transactions are also independent and unaware of each other.

Your business transaction (saving entities in a loop) spans multiple technical transactions.

*is there any way I can remove the other two data which got saved to Database successfully without writing a separate function for removing the data individually?* - **So no, there is no out of the box solution**. You have to write your custom rollback logic, to delete the saved entities from previous transactions.

If your use case allows it, you could wait for the loop to end in Microservice1 and then initiate a single external rest call to Microservice2, the payload of the call would be a list of entities, it would be a bulk save. This way, either all entities are saved, or none, plus if the save fails in Microservice2, you could also rollback Microservice1.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "Transactions" or "Saga" : https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html